# Group_Concat in pairs of nth

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, concatenation, sql-server-group-concat

I have a query that I normally `group_concat`. I need to know if `dbo.group_concat` has the ability to pair the result of a query into pairs of 3 (as an example).

For example:

```
select size, pattern, dbo.group_concat(mass) mass 
from labels 
group by size, pattern
```

Result is

```
Size Pattern Mass 
-----------------------------------------------------------
234  ZYL     22.43,55.32,33.24,22.53,56.32,40.32,50.21,32.21
234  ZA      50.00,56.23,21.23,50.21
```

I'd like to have this result

```
Size Pattern  Mass
--------------------------------
234  ZYL      22.43,55.32,33.24
234  ZYL      22.53,56.32,40.32
234  ZYL      50.21,32.21
234  ZA       50.00,56.23,21.23
234  ZA       50.21
```

Comment: What's the logic behind? I don't think that there is such function is SSMS...

Comment: Change your `GROUP BY` condition to whatever you need.

Comment: You are using MySQL?

Comment: I'm Using MSSQL 2008 . Group by syntax will group on the first 2 columns but i need to split the mass values into pairs of 3 (in other works after every 3rd delimiter).This is purely to simplify the data as there are 100s of values in some results.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any `dbo.group_concat` by default. You may be using https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/ or you may be using something else. What you're using will affect what abilities it provides.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily, if we have a `group ID` column. This column will group rows per three, sorting the data by `[mass]` value. Since, we have not got such column, we need to calculated it. The steps as are as following:

1. we are using `ROW_NUMBER` function to sort the rows and know which three consequence rows form a group
2. then, we are using recursive common table expression (nothing too complicated) - just getting the first row of each `size, pattern` entity and then join the next row ... then join the next, until we get them all

This is full working example of the above:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [size] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[pattern] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[mass] DECIMAL(9,2)
);


INSERT INTO @DataSource ([size], [pattern], [mass])
VALUES (234, 'ZYL', 22.43)
      ,(234, 'ZYL', 55.32)
      ,(234, 'ZYL', 33.24)
      ,(234, 'ZYL', 22.53)
      ,(234, 'ZYL', 56.32)
      ,(234, 'ZYL', 40.32)
      ,(234, 'ZYL', 50.21)
      ,(234, 'ZYL', 32.21)
      --
      ,(234, 'ZA', 50.00)
      ,(234, 'ZA', 56.23)
      ,(234, 'ZA', 21.23)
      ,(234, 'ZA', 50.21);

WITH DataSource AS 
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [size], [pattern] ORDER BY [mass]) AS [RowID]
    FROM @DataSource
),
RecursiveDataSource AS
(
    SELECT [size], [pattern], [mass], [RowID]
          ,1 AS [Group]
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE [RowID] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.*
          ,R.[Group] + CASE WHEN (A.[rowID] - 1) % 3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM DataSource A
    INNER JOIN RecursiveDataSource R
        ON A.[size] = R.[size]
        AND A.[pattern] = R.[pattern]
        AND A.[RowID] - 1 = R.[rowID]
)
SELECT *
FROM RecursiveDataSource
ORDER BY [pattern], [RowID];
```

[image]

Now, in the final `SELECT` we just need to add your initial code, but grouping by the `[group]` column also:

```
SELECT [size], [pattern], [dbo].[group_concat] ([mass])
FROM RecursiveDataSource
GROUP BY [size], [pattern], [Group];
```

In my system, the above yields this:

[image]

Some considerations:

- I am ordering the values by the `mass` value (and in your example, you are not) - this is completely up to you; you can change the ordering to whatever you need, even using `SELECT 1` in the `ORDER BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER` function to get some random ordering;
- using recursive CTE for large table can lead to bad performance; be sure have tested the code with your real data first;
- the `concatenate` SQL CLR function on my systems allows setting order; in my case, I have concatenated the rows using the `RowID` value; if your function does not allow specifying such order you rely on the .net code behind it, so you can get different order of the values in the final CSV list.

Comment: Thank you so much .It's working 100% . Thank you for your time an effort .Regards

Comment: @PieterHenkelman https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/201336 accept the answer, then.